# The spacing is not the same after defining the absolute position of the node？

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-node

I defined the absolute position of the node, and the difference between their vertical coordinates is fixed y. However, the distance between them is different in the picture display. How to solve it?

```
\documentclass[border=3pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzstyle{mynode}=[thick,rectangle,minimum size=5mm]
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}%[x=2.2cm,y=1.8cm]
    
 \def\x {5mm};
 \def\y {2mm};  

  \node[mynode] (20) at (0,5\y) {a};
  \node[mynode] (21) at (0,4\y) {b};
  \node[mynode] (22) at (0,3\y) {c};
  \node[mynode] (23) at (0,2\y) {d};
  \node[mynode] (24) at (0,\y) {e};
  \node[mynode] (25) at (0,0) {f};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: a]

Comment: You need `*` to trigger `pgfmath`.

Comment: The difference between e and f is 2mm. The difference between a and b, b and c, c and d, d and e is 10mm. `\y` is fixed, but the difference between `52mm` and `42mm` is different from that between `2mm` and `0`.

Comment: While you have probably seen things like `0.5\textwidth`, this notataion only works for `dimen` registers, not macros.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the second coordinate to be calculated (I assume) by `pgfmath`. In that case, you need to use `*` or some other way of triggering the calculation.

```
\documentclass[border=3pt,tikz]{standalone}
\tikzstyle{mynode}=[thick,rectangle,minimum size=5mm]
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}%[x=2.2cm,y=1.8cm]
    
 \def\x {5mm}
 \def\y {2mm}  

  \node[mynode] (20) at (0,5*\y) {a};
  \node[mynode] (21) at (0,4*\y) {b};
  \node[mynode] (22) at (0,3*\y) {c};
  \node[mynode] (23) at (0,2*\y) {d};
  \node[mynode] (24) at (0,\y) {e};
  \node[mynode] (25) at (0,0) {f};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note that the nodes are correctly placed in the following. They overlap a lot because there isn't enough space, but they just fit due to the shapes of the letters.

[image: nodes at calculated positions]

In the original code, you're placing them at 52mm, 42mm, 32mm, 22mm, 2mm and 0.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun:

Actually, I think tikz already defines `\x` so that `\x1`, `\x2` and `\x3` are legal expressions (the 1 etc. are arguments).

```
\documentclass[border=3pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzstyle{mynode}=[thick,rectangle,minimum size=5mm]

\newlength{\myx}
\newlength{\myy}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}%[x=2.2cm,y=1.8cm]
    
 \myx=5mm
 \myy=2mm 

  \node[mynode] (20) at (0,5\myy) {a};
  \node[mynode] (21) at (0,4\myy) {b};
  \node[mynode] (22) at (0,3\myy) {c};
  \node[mynode] (23) at (0,2\myy) {d};
  \node[mynode] (24) at (0,\myy) {e};
  \node[mynode] (25) at (0,0) {f};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

Off topic:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\x#1{\@ifundefined{x#1}{\errmessage{Undefined control sequence:}}
  {\csname x#1\endcsname}}
\makeatother
\expandafter\dimendef\csname x1\endcsname=0
\begin{document}
\x1=1pt
\the\x1

\x2
\end{document}
```

Comment: But isn't this because `\myy` is a dimension? In the original question, the second coordinate was simply a number followed by a macro. But I agree using `\y` seems problematic (even if it seems to work). If you use `\def\myy{2mm}` without the `*`, you still get the OP's result. `\show\y` before the first `\def` gives undefined.

Comment: Also `\y5` gives an undefined control sequence error.

Comment: @cfr: I can create a \dimen register named `\x1`, but getting an error message for `\x2` was harder.

Comment: But  I thought the question was whether tikz defined `\x#1` or `\y#1`? That's how I read the beginning of your answer. But that doesn't seem to be the case. Am I just misunderstanding what you're saying?

Comment: That I actually named the register `\csname x1\endcsname` is irrelevant.  Any name would do.  OTOH, since there is no LaTeX equvalent to `\p1=\p2`, the tikz parser has to be handling at least some of the "registers" directly.  Just how much, no clue.

Comment: But you say **tikz** defines `\x` so `\x1` is legal. I think that's true in some contexts, but not in `\coordinate (\x1,0pt);`. I think I'm confused about what you meant by the bit at the beginning of your answer and we're talking past each other, maybe?

Comment: `let ...` is different ....